Strange Noise in Rendered Viewport [4.2.3]
I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this kind of thing but this is something I'm 100% stumped on. I've asked this on the subreddit but haven't seem to get any help so I'm just going to copy and paste what I wrote there.

Hey there, happy Halloween. So I haven't used Blender in a while with the last version I used being around when 4.0 first started rolling out? And this is an issue I have NEVER had before since using 4.2.3 lately so I'm not sure what's going on.
But in the viewport, if I switch to the rendered setting I get this really strange noise look and I'm not sure what's going on? I've never, ever encountered this before.
I've checked jittered shadows, lowered samples, and turned off shadows but those haven't seemed to really help me.
I've noticed that it gets worse if I turn on raytracing, but did previous versions also use raytracing with Eevee? It's just something I never really paid any mind before because again; I haven't had this issue up until recently with this version.
When I disable raytracing it does look better, but even I can still notice some pixelation-like noise on occasions and I don't really like that, I'm just really confused on what's going on and I hope someone can work with me on how to fix this.
I don't know if it makes a difference but I'm using Blender off of Steam. Here are some images to show what I mean.

(For the first image, look close at the "LET'S ROCK" poster and you'll see the shadows looking pixelated)

Again I could really use some help here please, I've NEVER had this issue until using the latest version and I'm so confused on what's going on. I highly doubt it has anything to do with my computer considering again; previous versions worked just fine, it's only the recent ones.
